# Group orders with Ramda

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

I made some crude code using RamdaJS to essentially group orders by their states. There are some nested structures. Currently, I have a working code, but I wondering if Ramda can perhaps help to clean that up more? I've added TypeScript annotations to present (simplified) structures more clearly.

I've also prepared codesandbox with example data: https://codesandbox.io/s/yqwm2p65zz

```
import * as R from 'ramda'

export default function(orders: Order[], orderListing: OrderListing[]) {
  const pluckStateEnum = (orderState: OrderState) => orderState.enum

  const ordersByState = (states: OrderStateEnum[]) =>
    orders.filter(
      (order: Order) =>
        !R.isEmpty(
          R.intersection(R.map(pluckStateEnum, order.orderStates), states),
        ),
    )

  return orderListing.map(listing => ({
    id: listing.id,
    orders: ordersByState(listing.orderStateEnums).map(order => order.id),
  }))
}

interface Order {
  id: string
  orderStates: OrderState[]
}

interface OrderState {
  enum: OrderStateEnum
}

interface OrderListing {
  id: string
  orderStateEnums: OrderStateEnum[]
}

type OrderStateEnum =
  | 'RECEIVED'
  | 'PAID'
  | 'UNPAID'
  | 'CUSTOMER_NOTIFIED'
  | 'FINISHED'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a couple Typescript notes:

- I assume you cannot change the data format, if you can, I would highly recommend renaming the `enum` property. `enum` is a keyword in Typescript.
- `OrderStateEnum` should be represented as an actual enum. I'd also consider dropping the `Enum` suffix.

  ```ts
  enum OrderStateEnum {
    RECEIVED = 'RECEIVED',
    PAID = 'PAID',
    UNPAID = 'UNPAID',
    CUSTOMER_NOTIFIED = 'CUSTOMER_NOTIFIED',
    FINISHED = 'FINISHED'
  }
  ```
- Avoid default exports - see [Typescript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/defaultIsBad.html)

You are correct, Ramda can help simplify this code.

- `pluckStateEnum` is equivalent to `R.prop('enum')`
- `ordersByState` can have the nesting level reduced, additionally, checking if the intersection of two arrays is empty can be better represented with `R.any(R.contains(R.__, arr1), arr2)`. I also use `chain` to flatten the array while getting properties.

  ```js
  const ordersByState = states => orders.filter(R.pipe(
    R.prop('orderStates'), 
    R.chain(R.prop('enum')),
    R.any(R.contains(R.__, states))
  ))
  ```

  With this change, the function becomes much easier to read. See the [repl](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20grouping%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%271%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20orderStateEnums%3A%20%5B%27RECEIVED%27%5D%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%275%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20orderStateEnums%3A%20%5B%27FINISHED%27%5D%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%5D%0A%0Aconst%20orders%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%22first%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20orderStates%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enum%3A%20%22RECEIVED%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enum%3A%20%22PAID%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%22second%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20orderStates%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enum%3A%20%22RECEIVED%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enum%3A%20%22UNPAID%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%22third%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20orderStates%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enum%3A%20%22RECEIVED%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enum%3A%20%22UNPAID%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enum%3A%20%22CUSTOMER_NOTIFIED%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%22fourth%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20orderStates%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enum%3A%20%22RECEIVED%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enum%3A%20%22UNPAID%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enum%3A%20%22CUSTOMER_NOTIFIED%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%22fifth%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20orderStates%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enum%3A%20%22FINISHED%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enum%3A%20%22PAID%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Afunction%20group%28orders%2C%20orderListing%29%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20ordersByState%20%3D%20states%20%3D%3E%20orders.filter%28R.pipe%28%0A%20%20%20%20R.prop%28%27orderStates%27%29%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20R.chain%28R.prop%28%27enum%27%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20R.any%28R.contains%28R.__%2C%20states%29%29%0A%20%20%29%29%0A%0A%20%20return%20orderListing.map%28listing%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20listing.id%2C%0A%20%20%20%20orders%3A%20ordersByState%28listing.orderStateEnums%29.map%28R.prop%28%27id%27%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%7D%29%29%0A%7D%0A%0Agroup%28orders%2C%20grouping%29%0A%0A).

For completeness, here is how I would implement this function:

```
function group(orders, orderListing) {
  const ordersByState = states => orders.filter(R.pipe(
    R.prop('orderStates'), 
    R.chain(R.prop('enum')), // you might know this as flatMap
    R.any(R.contains(R.__, states))
  ))

  return orderListing.map(listing => ({
    id: listing.id,
    orders: ordersByState(listing.orderStateEnums).map(R.prop('id')),
  }))
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, that looks really good. Thank you very much. I definitely want to learn Ramda more and this looks like a good start.

Comment: Regarding enum naming, I don't write the backend, I could suggest it, but it's quite a widespread naming and it would require a lot of refactoring in the end. So far it did not have any issues anywhere.

I know about default exports, I just used one in here for a simplicity. I don't use those anymore :)